# The size of a float div is not adapting to his content

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have a problem with my current project. Im designing a playing card table.

I have two areas in my game table, one for the Player 1 put his games and the other to Player 2 put his games.

A player can have a lot of games and I need to show this games separated in the respectively player area.

In my html, I have a div representing that player area with a class named "canasta".
[image: The Player Area and the html]

The problem is that I need put the cards one above another, and for do this I use "margin-left: -50px". **This margins should decrease the size of the parent div, right? But this is not happening.**

And then, the "canastas" have this empty space between them.

My "canasta" class use this css properties:

```
display: inline-block;
float: left;
```

Someone could help me?

A link of all source code:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5GEKEMzvk0nbVlSb2FscFl2cE0&usp=sharing

An example of what happens:
http://jsfiddle.net/dzf49ycd/

Thanks,
Renan.

Comment: When something is floated, it is automatically display:block;. You should be able to remove the float.

Comment: Hmm, but all of the divs children of the "canastas" div are floated, all of them are displayed side by side, this is ok...The problem is the space between them...I put a margin-left: -50px for each card, this should result in a decrease of the parent content...

Comment: Not without seeing all of the relevant CSS (or being able to get a link to the page).

Comment: I uploaded all the html/css in my GDrive. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5GEKEMzvk0nbVlSb2FscFl2cE0&usp=sharing

Comment: I see your point, Renan. Whether floated left, or displayed inline-block, the canasta DIV should shrink. I don't have an answer for you, but perhaps this fiddle can help explain the problem to new readers: http://jsfiddle.net/dzf49ycd/